# How to send a fake ICMP response?

Tags: go, ip, packet, icmp

I am using TAP-Windows Adapter to capture all IP packets.
And for some reason, I want to fake ICMP packet (fake src and dst),in order to let programs on my device get wrong ICMP delay. (maybe quick response or forward to other IP)

I knew scapy can send fake ICMP packet, but now I want to use golang to achieve this.

I using `net.DialIP("ip4:icmp",fake_src,fake_dst)`, maybe as `raw socket`.
However, I get an error :`dial ip4:icmp 8.8.8.8->10.9.9.2: bind: The requested address is not valid in its context.`

So what should I do?

Comment: Maybe I should use `syscall.Socket()` to get `raw socket`? I have not tried this...